# What can I substitute for cornstarch?

Tags: cornstarch

Cornstarch is used in various recepies for many purposes but sometime it is not available in kitchen. So, what can I substitute for cornstarch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genrally speaking, you can substitute any pure starch for corn starch.  This would include:

- Potato starch
- Arrowroot powder
- Tapioca starch

Usually, you can use the same amounts you would have used for corn starch.  You cannot substitute flour in the same amounts without changing the flavor and/or texture of the dish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular flour.

There are other thickener out there, but maybe not as readily available as flour or cornstarch.

See: https://www.swansonvitamins.com/blog/jenna/thickening-ingredients

Comment: Well, kinda @Max, it depends on the application. Cornstarch as a thickener sure, but what about others?

Comment: You can also use potato starch, which is found in large quantities in stores in the spring time around the Jewish holiday of Passover, when leaven cannot be consumed.